# Пунктуация в предложении с вставной конструкцией

Tags: пунктуация

Розенталь пишет, что перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура первой части основного предложения:

> Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, – какой ужас! – и руки
> бессильно опустились у него.

Здесь запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения.

С другой стороны, в примерах из других источников видно, что запятая стоит не перед первым тире, а перед вторым:

> Многие названия, требующие постановки кавычек при употреблении в
> пределах текста – в составе синтаксических конструкций в сочетании с
> другими словами, – вне таких конструкций пишутся без данного
> выделительного знака.

> Сказуемое, в котором лексическое и грамматическое значения выражены
> одним словом – глаголом в форме какого-нибудь наклонения, – называется
> простым глагольным.

Чем это можно объяснить?

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу противоречия.В первом примере вставная конструкция относится к сложноподчинённому предложению, во втором входит в причастный оборот, запятая указывает на конец оборота,в третьем относится только к придаточному предложению. Уберите вставную конструкцию -  всё встанет на свои места: Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его,  и руки бессильно опустились у него. Многие названия, требующие постановки кавычек при употреблении в пределах текста ,  вне таких конструкций пишутся без данного выделительного знака.
Сказуемое, в котором лексическое и грамматическое значения выражены одним словом ,  называется простым глагольным.Всё на своих местах, добавится вставная конструкция - добавятся тире, а запятые будут играть роль знака конца конструкций.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Можно ли написать так: Сказуемое, в котором лексическое и грамматическое значения выражены одним словом – глаголом в форме какого-нибудь наклонения, называется простым глагольным.

по правилу _второе тире опускается_ если после приложения следует запятая.

Comment: Да. Правило это оправдывает.